# Google wallet mysteriously appeared on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, chromium

As I was using my desktop running Ubuntu 14.10, out of the blue a Cairo-Dock indicator appeared asking if I wanted to use the newly installed "**Google Wallet**" application.  Cairo-dock does this whenever a new application is installed or a new .desktop file is added to /usr/share/applications.

I was not in the process of installing software and no software updates had occurred today to my knowledge.

Upon searching my computer, I could not find "Google Wallet," except via the Cairo-Dock:

[image: Google wallet mysteriously appeared on Ubuntu 14.10]

It is not in `/usr/share/applications` or `/opt`.  It is not located by searching Nautilus.

Does anyone know what this is and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Same Problem (Virus?)
found it in /usr/bin/chromium-browser --profile-directory=Default --app-id=nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda never seen befor

Comment: Same happened to me in Debian! it is the most weird moment I ever got while working on my computer!

Comment: I've just had the same thing happen to me - any explanation, yet? Currently running clamav recursively across my entire system just in case. EDIT: Also, I can also confirm that curious app thing /usr/bin/chromium-browser with that strange id - that's what the strange added .desktop file points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As locke said - Google Wallet is a plug-in for Googles payment system of Google Chrome(ium).

What really happened was that the browser "installed" an application starter (a `.desktop` file) in the users directory:

```
~/.local/share/applications/chrome-nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda-Default.desktop
```

This starter simply launches Chrome with the wallet app. Cairo-dock keeps an eye on `/usr/share/applications` as well as `~/.local/share/applications` so it noticed the new application and informed us about it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Google Wallet
Exec=/usr/lib/chromium/chromium --profile-directory=Default --app-id=nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda
Icon=chrome-nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda-Default
NoDisplay=true
StartupWMClass=crx_nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda
```

Pay attention to the "NoDisplay" entry which hides this application in all menus. Programs like `alacarte` show all available entries so it's easy to remove the starter with a menu editor.

If you're brave you can execute the following command in a terminal to get rid of the starter:

```
rm ~/.local/share/applications/chrome-nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda-Default.desktop
```

I have to state that it's the first time that I'm very happy about this (otherwise nagging) feature - I went like "WTF?!!1" o0 when it happened. I think it's an absolute no-go to secretly slip me an unwanted browser app and the corresponding starter. Even if it was done clearly visible and without this clandestine behavior it is an affront.

**Don't touch my home you Google tools!**

Seems it's time to set up a virtual box for this program. If I wouldn't need it for development it would have been purged from my machine now.

Comment: The first half of  your answer is fine the second half unnessary opinion maybe you can improve it

Answer (score 4):

It is a plug-in for Chromium browser.
I guess it comes from google itself to introduce their payment system Google Wallet.
I deleted this plug-in (the folder) at `~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda`.
Is not new published.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I removed all extensions from ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions w/o any side effects

Comment: The same happened to me on Ubuntu 14.04 - the only googely thing I was aware of is that Chromium was running. WTF is google doing?